# React/JSX not taking my onClick handler whereas basic HTML does

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, jsx

When I click on the span, I would like the user to stay on the current page

This one is in regular HTML (it works) :

```
<a href="https://google.fr">
  Go to google
  <span onclick="console.log('toto'); return false;">
    | Stay on current page
  </span>
</a>
```

However, with this react 16.2 version, the google link catches the event before the span :

```
const Link = () =>
  <a href="https://google.fr">
    Go to google
    <span onClick={(e) => {console.log('toto'); return false;}}>
      | Stay on current page
    </span>
  </a>;

ReactDOM.render(<Link />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Do you know how to fix it ? (and why it happens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, applying Drew Reese solution works.
However, in the true application (mixed react 16.2/angular environment), angular catches the native client event before React emits its synthetic event.

I had to use a reference to handle the native dom event.

```
class Link extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref.addEventListener('click', e => { 
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <a href="https://google.fr">
        Go to google
        <span ref={(ref) => {this.ref = ref}}>
          | Stay on current page
        </span>
      </a>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've done the half angular-half react application before... it's not great. Kudos for figuring out the angular half though.

Answer (score 1):

[Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

> As of v0.14, returning `false` from an event handler will no longer stop
> event propagation. Instead, `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.preventDefault()`
> should be triggered manually, as appropriate.

```
const Link = () =>
  <a href="https://google.fr">
    Go to google
    <span
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault(); // for good measure
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('toto');
      }}
    >
      | Stay on current page
    </span>
  </a>;
```

Comment: This works great on CodePen (the event is catched by the span first), however, in my true application it still fails (the redirection happens before the event is catched)...

Comment: My issue is related to development of a custom plugin for Grafana. Grafana is a SPA that uses both Angular (for routes) and React at runtime.
When I build a link <a>, I guess that the native click event is catched by Angular, before react synthetic event is emitted...